# Dropdown menu is to big

Tags: html, css, dropdown

Hello so im trying to do dropdown menu by clicking on button but its elements are way to big , what im I doing wrong? I realy im like going insane, can you please help me in this art that is coding ?
It doesnt have any problem just that its ugly
edit: i have updated and posted full css code to see if u guys can help me

```css
         html {
        background: #e6e9e9;
        background-image: linear-gradient(270deg, rgb(230, 233, 233) 0%, rgb(216, 221, 221) 100%);
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }

    body {
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
        color: #545454;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 7.5;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 2em 2em 4em;
    }

    .button {
      background-color: #4a7bb5;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 5px 32px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: cute;
      font-size: 32px;
    }
    .button:hover{
     box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
     background-color: #4a7bb5;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 5px 32px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: cute;
      font-size: 32px;
    }
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}






    p {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #52d6ff;
    }

    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        color: #237543;
        font-weight: 600;
        line-height: 0;
        font-size: 50px;

    }
    hr { display: block; height: 1px;
        border: 1; border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        margin: 1em 0; padding: 0; }

    h2 {
        margin-top: 1.3em;
    }

    a {
        color: #0083e8;
    }

    b, strong {
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    samp {
        display: none;
    }

    img {

        background: transparent;

    }

    @keyframes colorize {
        0% {
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
            filter: grayscale(100%);
        }
        100% {
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
            filter: grayscale(0%);
        }
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family:cute;
      src: url(cute.ttf);
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family:opensans;
      src: url(opensans.ttf);
    }
```

```html
 <HR size=2 style="color: aqua"></HR>
    <button class="button" onclick="mainpage();">Main Page</button>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="button">Art</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Acrilic</a>
    <a href="#">Carvão</a>
    <a href="#">Paint</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem... https://jsfiddle.net/qz5oba6h/

Comment: Likely you have css code that is effecting the drop down that you have not added to your example code as I too can not reproduce this issue. My fiddle had the exact same results as @sanriot

Comment: @dalelandry i have updated the css code , are you aware of any anomaly there?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you mean by drop down menu is too big

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<body>` has a `line-height: 7.5` style which is getting inherited by your dropdown's anchor tags.

Either remove this style, or otherwise reset it at some point between your `<body>` and `.dropdown-content a` elements. For example:

```css
.dropdown {
    ...
    line-height: normal;
}
```

```css
html {
        background: #e6e9e9;
        background-image: linear-gradient(270deg, rgb(230, 233, 233) 0%, rgb(216, 221, 221) 100%);
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }

    body {
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
        color: #545454;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 7.5;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 2em 2em 4em;
    }

    .button {
      background-color: #4a7bb5;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 5px 32px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: cute;
      font-size: 32px;
    }
    .button:hover{
     box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
     background-color: #4a7bb5;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 5px 32px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: cute;
      font-size: 32px;
    }
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: normal;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}






    p {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #52d6ff;
    }

    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        color: #237543;
        font-weight: 600;
        line-height: 0;
        font-size: 50px;

    }
    hr { display: block; height: 1px;
        border: 1; border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        margin: 1em 0; padding: 0; }

    h2 {
        margin-top: 1.3em;
    }

    a {
        color: #0083e8;
    }

    b, strong {
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    samp {
        display: none;
    }

    img {

        background: transparent;

    }

    @keyframes colorize {
        0% {
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
            filter: grayscale(100%);
        }
        100% {
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
            filter: grayscale(0%);
        }
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family:cute;
      src: url(cute.ttf);
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family:opensans;
      src: url(opensans.ttf);
    }
```

```html
<HR size=2 style="color: aqua"></HR>
    <button class="button" onclick="mainpage();">Main Page</button>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="button">Art</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Acrilic</a>
    <a href="#">Carvão</a>
    <a href="#">Paint</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```